# How can I put the Routh path directly in the html of my Home and redirect to the other components

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Thats my Home.js

```
function Home() {

return (
    <div>
        <section className="sec1">
    <nav className="nav">
        <ul className="ulli">
            <li><i class="fas fa-thin fa-book-bookmark"></i></li>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Recipes</li>
            <li>Favourites</li>
            <li>Personal List</li>
            <li>Create Recipe</li> 
        </ul>
        <div className="btn1">
            <button className="btns">Sign Up</button>
            <button className="btnl">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
<h1 className="welcome">Welcome to UclIncop Recipes</h1>
<hr/>
  <article className="roword">
        <article className = "articlea">
            <img className="imgi"  src="https://www.wellplated.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Healthy-Air-Fryer-Salmon.jpg"/>
            <button className="sec2btn">Details</button>
        </article>
        <article class = "articlea">
            <img className="imgi" src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2019-01/14/15/asset/buzzfeed-prod-web-01/sub-buzz-6945-1547499531-1.jpg?downsize=900:*&amp;output-format=auto&amp;output-quality=auto"/>
            <button className="sec2btn">Details</button>
        </article>
        <article class = "articlea">
            <img className="imgi" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/39/51/7b/39517bf5ee252193fbd7bc4d1d2e89b6.jpg"/>
            <button className="sec2btn">Details</button>
        </article>
    </article>
    <p className="textp">
    Looking for inspiration on how to spice up salmon dinners? From a sweet-spicy marinade for whole grilled salmon to fiery wasabi mayo salmon fillets, and spicy smoked salmon sushi recipes, we have compiled this 
    versatile collection of showstopping salmon dishes that will satisfy the most ardent spice lovers!
    Salmon is marinated in a spicy Asian-inspired marinade, then cooked on a hot grill.Use cooked marinade as a dipping sauce or drizzle over salmon just before serving.
        </p>
        <article class="rowbreakor">
            <article className = "articles">
                <img className = "img2"src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYne5Tv-GWHCreN0XonIv5vLfFdEOxRdThsg&amp;usqp=CAU"/>
                <h1>Recipe</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                    maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd2">Details</button>
            </article>
            <article  className = "articles">
                <img className = "img2" src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F34%2F2011%2F01%2F18232122%2Fcashew-chicken-kebabs-102899720.jpg"/>
                <h1>Recipe</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                    maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd2">Details</button>
            </article>
            <article  className = "articles">
                <img className = "img2" src="https://images.themodernproper.com/billowy-turkey/production/posts/2019/Best-Kid-Friendly-Recipes-1.jpg?w=1200&amp;auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=crop&amp;dm=1604880029&amp;s=62ecbc82edfd3a4b2b2864c7f147c3ed"/>
                <h1>Recipe</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                    maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd2">Details</button>
            </article>
        </article>
        <footer className="footer">
        <p>© All Rights Reserved to UclIncop</p>
    </footer>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

**I want the link Recipes to show my Recipe List component and so on
That's my RecipeList.js**

```
function Recipe List() {

    return (
        <div>
           <section className="sec4">
       <article className="artsec4">
        <article>
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYne5Tv-GWHCreN0XonIv5vLfFdEOxRdThsg&amp;usqp=CAU"/>
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="https://imagesvc.meredithcorp.io/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.onecms.io%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F34%2F2011%2F01%2F18232122%2Fcashew-chicken-kebabs-102899720.jpg"/>
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                maxime...</p>
            <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
                <img src="https://www.gimmesomeoven.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/Roasted-Chickpea-Salad-Recipe-4-320x480.jpg"/>
                <h1>Recipe</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                    maxime...</p>
                    <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYne5Tv-GWHCreN0XonIv5vLfFdEOxRdThsg&amp;usqp=CAU"/>
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="https://cdn.loveandlemons.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/baked-eggs-recipe.jpg"/>
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="https://images.themodernproper.com/billowy-turkey/production/posts/2019/Best-Kid-Friendly-Recipes-1.jpg?w=1200&amp;auto=compress%2Cformat&amp;fit=crop&amp;dm=1604880029&amp;s=62ecbc82edfd3a4b2b2864c7f147c3ed"/>
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="https://www.gimmesomeoven.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/How-To-Make-Fried-Rice-Recipe-2-1.jpg"/>
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="https://minimalistbaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/AMAZING-30-minute-HEALTHY-Chickpea-Shawarma-Wraps-with-a-simple-Garlic-Dill-Sauce-An-easy-weeknight-vegan-plantbased-meal-healthy-recipe-mediterranean-minimalistbaker.jpg"/>
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
                <img src="https://joyfoodsunshine.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/chicken-kebabs-recipe-1-360x480.jpg"/>
                <h1>Recipe</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                    maxime...</p>
                    <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRqV4YfDJN4QYLy_8FfoQRoM3uOukP0uEKvibe6rY4tSSuBus7pjshUmMiJFbxaWZH8wi8&amp;usqp=CAU"/>
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="https://therecipecritic.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/strawberrybruschetta3-368x463.jpg"/>
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="https://www.simplyrecipes.com/thmb/De8yp7CBzVdq7N32Zbb7bKDXtv4=/440x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/Simply-Recipes-Tandoori-Chicken-LEAD-01-7767f2892b824b24b65213f3ba28ff8c.jpg"/>
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="https://www.acouplecooks.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Sauce-for-Scallops-001.jpg"/>
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRCnRhPVRY7R2721S6faEhMTGjxfNZY5N5zBw&amp;usqp=CAU"/>
            <h1>Recipe</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                maxime...</p>
                <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
        <article>
                <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/38/d3/05/38d3056668dc3eb6b1184c57f8914a85.jpg"/>
                <h1>Recipe</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea magni sunt velit 
                    maxime...</p>
                    <button className="btnd">Details</button>
            <button className="favour"><i class="fas fa-solid fa-heart-circle-plus"></i></button>
        </article>
       </article>
    </section>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RecipeList;
```

Comment: Are you using `react-router`/`react-router-dom` or are you using `react-navigation` (*these are two rather different routing/navigation libraries*). What have you tried already on you own? Can you clarify what it is you are trying to accomplish? Can you cut some of the less relevant "fluff" from these two components so it's easier to see what you want to be a link and what you want to render on routes?

Comment: I really don't know what I should use. For example I want <li>Recipes</li> to be a link to the Recipes component and see the html of my Recipes component, like if the component has only h2 inside it, I want to be redirected to that h2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to have the `Home` component render a link to a `"/recipes"` path that is rendering the `RecipeList` component then can use `react-router-dom` to render the app into a router component, the `App` component to render the routes, and the `Home` component render a `Link` in the unordered list.

Example:

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

App

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/recipes" element={<RecipeList />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Home

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

...

<nav className="nav">
  <ul className="ulli">
    <li>
      <i class="fas fa-thin fa-book-bookmark"></i>
    </li>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/recipes">Recipes</Link> // <-- render a Link
    </li>
    <li>Favourites</li>
    <li>Personal List</li>
    <li>Create Recipe</li>
  </ul>
  <div className="btn1">
    <button className="btns">Sign Up</button>
    <button className="btnl">Log in</button>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-put-the-routh-path-directly-in-the-html-of-my-home-and-redirect-to-the]

You might want to move the `nav` element out into its own component and render this outside a route so it's always available instead of only being rendered when the `Home` component is rendered.